# Why is dialogflow.DetectIntentRequest hanging in production but working locally in Flask with ReactJS Axios calls?

Tags: reactjs, flask, timeout, dialogflow-es

I'm using a ReactJS FE web app with Dialogflow ES with Flask as the backend server. I'm using Firebase for auth and Firestore as my DB.

Both the React web app and Flask backend are deployed on separate GA App Engine instances.

Whenever a user sends a message in ReactJS, an Axios call with the message is sent to Flask.  The auth token is decrypted for user id and the message gets enriched before the call to Dialogflow.

Within Flask, I use the `dialogflow.DetectIntentRequest` command from the `google.cloud.dialogflow_v2` library. This is to make the call to Dialogflow which will parse the message before running the webhook and sending a response message in React.

In theory this should work and it almost does!  It works perfectly locally but once it's deployed to App Engine, the `dialogflow.DetectIntentRequest` just hangs until the Gunicorn timeout kicks in.

Locally it all runs in under 2secs.

There are no errors in the logs, simply a status 502 code.  I figured any CORS issues would be picked up here.

I've tried debugging by running the React app in prod with the Dialogflow webhook set to the local Ngrok address - again this works perfectly.

The data to be returned from Dialgflow is only a few sentences and it's not a complicated intent ("Show Menu").

Does anyone have any ideas one what might cause this? It feels like a connectivity issue but there are no firewall rules between my App Engines.  Maybe it's a port thing?

Would love some help with this!

ReactJS Axios Call:

```
axios.post(
      'https://myflaskserver.appspot.com/api/v1/dialog-flow-proxy',
      {
        queryInput: {
          text: {
            text: message,
            languageCode: 'en-GB',
            timezoneOffset: new Date().getTimezoneOffset(),
          },
        },
      },
    )
      .then((response) => {
        console.log('response: ', response.data);
        const fulfillment = response.data.payload;
        this.actionProvider.setBotResponse(fulfillment);
        this.actionProvider.setLoading(false);

      })
```

Flask Webhook:

```
@app.route('/api/v1/webhook', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def webhook():

    req = request.get_json(silent=True, force=True)
    try:
        action = req.get('queryResult').get('action')
    except AttributeError:
        return 'json error'

    if action == 'show.Commands':
        res = show_commands(req) # Refactor complete

        print('Action: ' + action)
        print('Response: ' + res)
        return res
```

Flask Proxy Routing:

```
@app.route('/api/v1/dialog-flow-proxy', methods=['POST'])
def dialogflow_call():
    try:
        response = handle_dialogflow_call()
        return make_response(response)
    
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Detect Intent:

```
session_client = dialogflow.SessionsClient(credentials=credentials)
    session = session_client.session_path(project_id, f"{session_id}")
    text_input = dialogflow.TextInput(text=f"{message}", language_code='en-GB')
    query_input = dialogflow.QueryInput(text=text_input)
    
    try:
        intent_request = dialogflow.DetectIntentRequest(session=session, query_input=query_input,
                                                    query_params={
                                                        "payload": custom_parameters
                                                        })

        response = session_client.detect_intent(intent_request)
```

Timeout:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7C3et.png)

I even tried building the request instead of using and posting to `https://dialogflow.googleapis.com/v2` but again, it just hangs before timing out.